# BLAS Functions Dgemm but all matrices are multiplied by a Scalar

Tags: c++, blas, cblas

Is there any Dgemm like matrix call that scales the a and b matrix? 
(A, B, C are scalars).

IE 
   c = C * c + (A*op(a)) * (B*op(b));

Bonus points is therer any reason this isn't supported or is it just uncommon in Linear-Algebra and therefor generally unwarranted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard BLAS interface does not provide a direct mean to scale both `A` and `B` matrices independently (in this jargon, they usually devote uppercase letters for matrices/vectors and lowercase for scalars). See the [MKL cblas documentation for cblas_?gemm](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-cblas-gemm) (it will be the same across BLAS implementations).

What you can do though is to generate the scaled version of `B` with an intermediate call, setting `a` and `b` to zero:

```
C = c.*C + (0.*A) * (0.*B)
```

However, if you decompose the matrix multiplication into single operations (example in row-major order):

```
for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
  for( j = 0; j < M; j++ ) {
    for( ii = 0; ii < K; ii++ ) {
      C[i][j] = C[i][j] + a*A[i][ii]*B[ii][j];
    }
  }
}
```

You will see that the scaling affects both matrices' elements. Since scalar product is commutative and associative, using an `a` argument equal to the product of both your scalars has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, dgemm does this, by using a simple multiplication property. Just refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication#Scalar_multiplication_of_matrices).

```
c = C*c + (A*op(a))*(B*op(b))
c = C*c + A*(op(a))*B)*op(b)
c = C*c + A*(B*op(a))*op(b)
c = C*c + (A*B)*op(a)*op(b)
```